# Next referral on the front page not working

Tags: django

I have login link, with a next parameter, so the user is redirected back to the page he came from.

Like this

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">
```

This works fine everywhere except on the front page.

Then I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'request.path' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.example.com/account/login/?next=/',
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

## Edit:

Updated question with the `a` element.

Comment: It looks like django is expecting a valid value, and it is getting `request.path` as a string - Do you have quotes around `request.path` or some logic that is treating this as a string instead of a context variable ?

Comment: Updated question with the link.